# Add superscript and subscript for pdf via migradoc

Tags: c#, html, migradoc

I am looking at a function that someone has written. The goal of the function to read html tags and format html tags appropriately for a pdf via `MigraDoc`.

This is the definition of the function.

`private Boolean RecursiveFormattedParagraph(Document d, Paragraph para, HtmlNode currentNode, ListInfo listinfo, Boolean listFlag, TextFormat currentFormat) {`

It is working for the tags that the program currently supports (i.e. `<b>, <i>`).

How can I add support for `subscript` and `superscript`? I have done some research and `FormattedText` seems to be the appropriate method here. But as a novice C# developer, I am not quite sure how to integrated it into the program.

Comment: You have to modify code you are not showing here. I don't think a bounty makes this question answerable.

Answer (score 5):

`MigraDoc` has an element called `FormattedText` which supports what you are looking for. I dont know how did you search for it but just a simple google search and I found what you were looking for.

[MigraDoc Sample: Hello MigraDoc](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloMigraDoc-sample.ashx?HL=formattedtext) is the documentation from MigraDoc. the following is from the sample provided by MigraDoc:

```
formattedText = paragraph.AddFormattedText("subscript");
formattedText.Subscript = true;

paragraph.AddText(" or ");

formattedText = paragraph.AddFormattedText("superscript");

formattedText.Superscript = true;
```